# CSS positioning — fixed > relative > absolute

Tags: css, css-position

Maybe this is noobish, however: Is it possible to have a `fixed` positioned container with some `relative` positioned containers in it and which themselves contain a stack of elements arranged with an `absolute` position to be able to use `z-index` to stack them on top of each other?

http://jsfiddle.net/A82b2/14/

**My problem:** Unfortunately instead of having multiple stacks, I end up with just one stack. 
My goal is to have image stacks floating next to each other like in this picture, instead of all the stacks positioned on top of each other. My goal:

[image: Goal layout]

Thanks for your wisdom!

Comment: Like if you change `position:absolute;` in `.stack-item`? http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/34kwp/

Comment: have you tried using absolute position on the imgs and using z-index?

Comment: Thanks, but that's the problem, if I use position: absolute, the stacks are not positioned relatively to each other but on top of each other. (Updated the jsfiddle and the image)

Comment: have you tried giving a width and height to .stack? Do they overflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is occurring because your relatively-positioned `.stack`s have no flow-affecting content inside them (i.e. content that is not absolutely or fixed-positioned) to expand their width and height beyond zero. If you apply the width and height of your `.stack-item` (i.e. `10em`) directly to your `.stack`, you'll see your single stack split into multiple stacks as intended.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer and the answer below in combination helped solve my problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The way you would do that is by `position:absolute;` and `z-index`. To solve your problem of the stacks being on top of each other, wrap the stacks in a div:

```
<div class="wrap">
<img class="one" src="http://lorempizza.com/500/500">
<img class="two" src="http://lorempizza.com/500/500">
<img class="three" src="http://lorempizza.com/500/500">
</div>
```

And give it CSS like this:

```
.wrap{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    display:block;
    width:600px;
    height:600px;
}
```

Then you need to create the photo stacks by using absolute positioning and z-index's:

```
img{
    position:absolute;
    }
.one{
    top:50px;
    left:50px;
    z-index:3;
}
.two{
    top:60px;
    left:60px;
    z-index:2;
}
.three{
    top:70px;
    left:70px;
    z-index:1;
```

}

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/M5Ebx/4/show/)
[And Coding](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/M5Ebx/4/)

Comment: Hey! Thanks very very much for your fiddle, but unfortunately my problem still remains: If I put the wraps (and pizzas…ha!) into a fixed positioned container with 100% dimensions, the layout inside breaks.
JSFiddle update: http://jsfiddle.net/M5Ebx/6/

Comment: Thanks! Your answer and the answer above in combination helped solve my problem! Thanks!